# Why is firefox 4 not HW accelerated?

Tags: firefox, hardware-acceleration

At first i thought it was my computer but then i tried chrome. Why isnt firefox not hardware accelerated? The first screenshot shows chrome at 23% usage. The 2nd shows 59%. I have 2 cpus which is why it isnt 100% usage. The game pictured is [biolab](http://playbiolab.com/)

[image: chrome]
[image: Firefox]

---

Heres the text for about:support

Application Basics

```
    Name
    Firefox

    Version
    4.0

    User Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0

    Profile Directory

      Open Containing Folder

    Enabled Plugins

      about:plugins

    Build Configuration

      about:buildconfig
```

Extensions

```
    Name

    Version

    Enabled

    ID
```

Modified Preferences

```
  Name

  Value

    accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar
    0

    browser.places.importBookmarksHTML
    false

    browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion
    2

    browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID
    20110303194838

    browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone
    rv:2.0

    extensions.lastAppVersion
    4.0

    gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.enabled
    true

    network.cookie.prefsMigrated
    true

    places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages
    127602

    privacy.sanitize.migrateFx3Prefs
    true
```

Graphics

```
    Adapter Description
    Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family

    Vendor ID
    8086

    Device ID
    2a42

    Adapter RAM
    Unknown

    Adapter Drivers
    igdumd64 igd10umd64 igdumdx32 igd10umd32

    Driver Version
    8.15.10.2202

    Driver Date
    8-25-2010

    Direct2D Enabled
    true

    DirectWrite Enabled
    true (6.1.7600.16385, font cache n/a)

    WebGL Renderer
    Google Inc. -- ANGLE -- OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 0.0.0.541)

    GPU Accelerated Windows
    1/1 Direct3D 10
```

Comment: Because the Firefox developers didn't implement it?

Answer (score 7):

Firefox 4 disables hardware acceleration for certain graphics chipsets they feel are unreliable.  To check from within Firefox whether GPU acceleration is enabled, type in `about:support` in your address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then look in the *Grahpics* section.  If it's enabled, the lines labeled `Direct2D Enabled` and `DirectWrite Enabled` will say `true`.  Otherwise it will say `false`.  This example has hardware acceleration enabled:

[image: Firefox about:support with graphics acceleration enabled]

You can manually enable hardware acceleration.  To do so, browse to `about:config`, click *I'll be careful, I promise!*, and type `webgl` into the *Filter box*.  Then, just double-click on the `webgl.force-enabled` property in the lower pane to toggle it from `false` to `true`.  Close out of Firefox and restart it for the changes to take effect.

[image: Firefox about:config with webgl.force-enabled property highlighted]

If you have trouble, you can start Firefox in Safe Mode, either by locating `Mozilla Firefox (Safe Mode)` in the Windows start menu or adding the `-safe-mode` switch to the `firefox` command.  Hardware acceleration is always disabled in Safe Mode.  You can then perform the above steps to change the setting back to default.

Comment: I edited my question with the copy/paste from about:support. Using setting force to true does not help

Comment: @acidzombie24:  According to your output. hardware acceleration is enabled and working in Firefox.  The excess processor usage might be related to differences between Mozilla's [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) JavaScript engine and Google's [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).  The two browsers are constantly competing to improve speed and I'm afraid resource usage might have been left on the backburner.  Also, hardware acceleration is not enabled in Chrome by default.  You can enable it by visiting `about:flags` if you want to test the difference with it enabled.

Comment: WTF!?! I enabled HW. How the F is SW faster then HW! I get the same performance as firefox and a blank screen after the logo instead of the actual title screen and game. I implemented 2D rendering in SW before, it was extremely slow (especially with alpha). I dont understand how this performance could happen.

Comment: @acidzombie: "Firefox 4 disables hardware acceleration for certain graphics chipsets *they feel are unreliable*"

Comment: @grawity: I am still WTFing on how SW is faster then HW. Sure FF may disable gfx but the performance 'appears' to be the same with it on. Chrome performance is way better. But... SW cant be faster then HW.... (especially when i can play 3d games from valve or blizzard with real acceleration)